# Cómo descargar múltiples XML en un ZIP?

Tags: php, xml, zip

estoy tratando de descagar multiples xml a traves de rutas que tengo guardada en mi base de datos, y estos los trato de guardar en un zip para descargarlos, pero me he quedado y no se que mas hacer, hasta el momento tengo este código:

```
 $zipname = "archivs.zip";
$sqlquery = $conn->prepare("SPU_PROVICIONES_CONXML ?,?,?,?,?");
$sqlquery->execute([$idSede, $fecIni, $fecFin, $ruc, $factura]);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE)){
    while($fila = $sqlquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $ruta = $fila['RUTA_ARCHIVO'];
        //La ruta es la siguiente '\\\\Server\\REPORTES\\Documentos\\fact.xml';
        echo $ruta;
        $zip->addFile($ruta);
    }    
    $zip->close();

    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zipname");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipname));
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$zipname");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    unlink($zipname);
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'Fallo';
}
```

Ejecutando ese código me descarga el zip, pero al momento de abrirlo, me sale un error:

[image: Es el error que me aparece]

Cuando descargo uno por uno los archivos si los descargo bien, ¿alguien a sufrido con un problema igual?

Comment: Sí, acabo de probar eso y nada, hay algún formato específico con el cual permita descargar el xml, yo le estoy mandando la ruta completa.

Comment: Confirma el tamaño de archivo que estás reportando el header. Confirma que el script tiene acceso a esa unidad de red. Sale algo en los logs de PHP?

Comment: De manera individual lo puedo descargar sin problema, el problema se presenta con el zip, en promedio se estan descargando 1500 archivos xml, en los logs no tengo errores.

Comment: Hm, son bastantes. El script termina sin novedades? (no suena loco que haya un timeout por tiempo de ejecución). Puedes probar con MUCHOS MENOS archivos? :) Prueba con cinco y revisa si el ZIP queda correcto.

Comment: Acabo de probar y me aparece el mismo error, ¿no tendrá algo que ver la ruta, como la estoy mandando?

Comment: Siguente prueba: intenta con archivos locales. Si funciona, ya sabes qué pasa

Comment: Sí, pero como digo, ya lo puedo descargar de manera individual, el problema es cuando traigo todas las rutas del query, y las quiero guardar en el zip.

Comment: Estimados, hasta el momento logré solucionar el problema de la siguiente manera, quité los dos ultimos header, y me descarga todos los xml, pero cuando llevé el código a producción me aparece el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pude resolver mi problema, al parecer las cabeceras estaban corrompiendo el archivo, lo que hice fue quitar algunas, el código quedaría así:

```
<?php
include '../../controlador/connec.inc.php';
$fecIni     = $_GET['fecIni'];
$fecFin     = $_GET['fecFin'];
$idSede   = $_GET['idSede'];
if($idSede  == ""){
    $idSede  = null;
}
$ruc = "%".$_GET['ruc']."%";
if($ruc == ""){
    $ruc = null;
}
$factura = "%".$_GET['factura']."%";
if($factura == ""){
    $factura = null;
}
$zipnme = "archivs.zip";
$sqlquery = $conn->prepare("SPU_PROVICIONES_CONXML ?,?,?,?,?");
$sqlquery->execute([$idSede, $fecIni, $fecFin, $ruc, $factura]);
$zipp = new ZipArchive;
if($zipp->open($zipnme, ZipArchive::CREATE)){
    while($file = $sqlquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $rute = $file['RUTA_ARCHIVO'];
        $zipp->addFile($rute);
    }    
    $zipp->close();
    ob_end_clean ();
    header("Content-type:application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$zipnme");
    header("Content-length:".filesize($zipnme));
    readfile("$zipnme");
}else{
    echo 'Fallo';
}
```

Las cabeceras que estaban corrompiedo son:

```
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
```